# What is the particular word for a person who thinks in-depth when s/he is lonely?

Tags: single-word-requests, british-english

I am looking for a word that describes a person who can think independently, and in-depth when s/he is alone. A single word is preferrable.

Comment: Can't most people think independently and in-depth when they are alone (and, presumably undisturbed)?

Comment: Engrossed in thoughts !

Comment: You mean they think melancholy thoughts, or they daydream, or they have productive thoughts (e.g. solving problems better when alone than in company)?

Comment: Do you refer to a meditative character (solitary thinking) or a  thoughtful analysis (in-depth) ?

Comment: Pensive. Engaged in, involving, or reflecting deep or serious thought.
"a pensive mood"

Comment: This is really a single-word request, so I changed the tag, but you should provide a sample sentence.

Comment: *contemplative*?

Answer (score 1):

A person who thinks in a particularly non-interactive (sharing, brainstorming) way is **introspective** [though this carries at least a hint of excessive withdrawal):

> *introspective* [adjective]
>
> examining and considering your own ideas, thoughts, and feelings,
> instead of talking to other people about them:
>
> - *She is famous for her introspective songs about failed relationships.*

[[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/introspective)]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @edwin-ashworth.